# Harvard referencing style in Elsarticle document class

Tags: bibliographies, elsarticle, harvard-style

I am writing an article in Latex using the elsarticle document class provided by Elsevier for their journals. For my writeup I wish to use the Harvard referencing system but cannot get this to work with the elsarticle document class.

How can I use the Harvard referencing system and the elsarticle document class in the same document?

Comment: By 'Harvard' I assume you mean an author-date style? If you are using a publishers class then presumably you are submitting to a journal: in this case, you really should stick to whatever they provide.

Comment: @JosephWright Correct, I am referring to the author-date style. I wish to use this style for my own purposes. When I finish I will use the publishers class. I just want a method to switch between the two styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `elsarticle` document class is compatible with many authoryear-based bibliography and citation callout styles.

If you want to stick with an Elsevier-supplied style while creating authoryear-style citations, you could use the file `elsarticle-harv.bst`, i.e., just issue the instruction

```
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
```

somewhere in your document.

If you wish to use some other authoryear-based bibliography style and also use the `natbib` package, be sure to load `natbib` with the option `authoryear`.

---

*Addendum*: Based on your follow-up comment, I now understand that you're not only interested in the "harvard" (aka, "authoryear") citation style in general, but also in  the [harvard](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/harvard/) citation management package; this package consists of a style file named (unsurprisingly) `harvard.sty` as well roughly half a dozen bibliography style files, one of which is `agsm.bst`.

I don't know for sure if the `harvard` *style file* is compatible with the `elsarticle` document class. However, you needn't actually load the `harvard` package in order to use the `agsm` style. Since you're already loading the `natbib` package (which is known to work well with the `elsarticle` document class), all you need to do is to load the [har2nat](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/har2nat) package as well. (I'll let you take a guess as to what loading `har2nat` accomplishes.) By loading both the `natbib` and `har2nat` packages, you are assured full interoperability with the `elsarticle` document class *and* the `hyperref` package -- while continuing to obtain the specific bibliography layout that's produced by the `agsm` bibliography style.

Of course, for the journal-ready version of your document, be sure to load `elsarticle-harv` instead of `agsm` and rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

Comment: I used the following code at the start of the document:    \documentclass[preprint,12pt,3p, numbers,authoryear]{elsarticle}     \usepackage{natbib} And at the end of the document I used:     \bibliographystyle{agsm}

Comment: **@Mico**: do you happen to know which of the Harvard bibliography styles - `agsm`, `aspr`, `dcu`, `jmr`, `jphysics8`, `kluwer`, `nederlands` - is closest (or hopefully identical) to the latest Elsevier Harvard style?

Comment: @Euclides - Sorry, I really don't make such comparative evaluations, although i have a hunch that none of them is *identical* to `elsarticle-harv`. I didn't even know until just now that there has been an update to `elsarticle-harv.bst` within the past year. Furthermore, I don't know how (or even if) the latest version of the `elsarticle-harv` differs from its predecessor. My general attitude towards creating bibliographies is to be meticulous about the *contents* of the bibliographic items, but to be agnostic as to which bibliography style is "good", let alone "better" than some other style.