# How can I change the references style from achemso to Harvard

Tags: bibliographies

My article was written in `achemso` style, but the editor requires us to change the references into 'Harvard style' (the target journal does not provide a template).
Is there any quick method that I can just change the reference into a 'Harvard style'?

I'm using Overleaf by the way.

My present file looks like this:

```
\documentclass[journal=jacsat,manuscript=article]{achemso}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} % Formula subscripts using \ce{}
\newcommand*\mycommand[1]{\texttt{\emph{#1}}}

\author{}
\author{}
\author{}
\affiliation[\]{}

\title[An \textsf{achemso} demo]

\begin{document}
...
\bibliography{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You didn't tell about your original ref styles or show any code about it in your example.

Comment: @hesham  I am using an ACS template in overleaf. And it contains only two files (.tex and .bib). I don't know where to find the ref style or its code...

Comment: `achemso` is the document class for submissions to journals of the American Chemical Society. The bibliography style is pretty much hard coded in that class. If you don't submit to an AChemSoc. journal you may be better of choosing a different document class.

Comment: If you followed moewe advice, you may select a more flexible class (e.g. elsarticle). For using harvard style with bibtex, have a look there https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3730/using-harvard-referencing-style.

Comment: Another good answer here for using harvard ref style with elsarticle class https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191970/harvard-referencing-style-in-elsarticle-document-class

Comment: One more comment: 'Harvard style' is not a well-defined style like APA style or Chicago style. 'Harvard style' usually just means author-year citations. So many different styles (with slightly different results) can claim to be 'Harvard style'. If you load `natbib` with the `authoryear` option (`\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}`) and use one of the `natbib` standard styles (`\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`) you get something that can be called 'Harvard style'.

Comment: Which journal? All the ACS ones use numeric styles and either a format based on JACS or Biochemistry

Comment: @JosephWright I used the JACS template. I changed to a Harvard template that I find online. Thanks @hesham and @moewe.  Another short question: how could I have a comma in the reference? When I use `\parencite{pauling1960}` it shows like this `(Pauling 1960)` rather than `(Pauling, 1960)`.